# Port 27005 closed - how can I force it to open?

Tags: networking, vps

I have a VPS (virtual server) hosted by [OVH](http://www.ovh.com/us/vps/).

I run GMod on the VPS;  port 27015 is the server port, and that is open.

However, 27005 is not.

IP tables is blank as I just flushed it and it is still closed. 27005 is crucial as it is the query port. How do I unblock 27005 for everyone?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

```
root@vps#####:~# nmap localhost -p 27005-27020 --unprivileged

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-02 11:31 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00014s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
27005/tcp closed flexlm5
27006/tcp closed unknown
27007/tcp closed flexlm7
27008/tcp closed unknown
27009/tcp closed flexlm9
27010/tcp closed flexlm10
27011/tcp closed unknown
27012/tcp closed unknown
27013/tcp closed unknown
27014/tcp closed unknown
27015/tcp closed unknown
27016/tcp closed unknown
27017/tcp closed unknown
27018/tcp closed unknown
27019/tcp closed unknown
27020/tcp closed unknown
```

Although it says :  Port 27015 is open on ##.##.###.###.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Ubuntu. Don't you just need to forward the port?

Comment: No.. Because I am using Ubuntu 14.04...

Comment: You're not making any sense. Where should the port be open? I'm assuming that it needs to be open on the network (ie. router) so that select PCs under that network can have access to that port. If so, that is port forwarding, which is router specific and doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a Ubuntu VPS..

Comment: Then this is out of my scope. You might want to reword your question so that if someone else reads it they'll have a easier time figuring out what exactly you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**what do a remote and local `nmap` probe look like?**

$`nmap localhost -p 27005-27020`

> ```
> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-01 16:59 CDT
> Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
> Host is up (0.00013s latency).
> Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.1.1
> PORT      STATE  SERVICE
> 27005/tcp closed flexlm5
> 27006/tcp closed unknown
> 27007/tcp closed flexlm7
> 27008/tcp closed unknown
> 27009/tcp closed flexlm9
> 27010/tcp closed flexlm10
> 27011/tcp closed unknown
> 27012/tcp closed unknown [...]
> ```

**Netstat**: `netstat -aunt` output?

For instance,

```
$ netstat -aunt | grep 2700
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27005           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**netcat *aka* `nc`** : Use something like `netcat` to test your system and firewall.

Set netcat to listen on port 27005.

**Local terminal or process:**

`$ nc -p 27005 -l`

**Remote and local access test:**

```
    
    $ telnet localhost 27005
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    ^C^]
```

If you're blocked remotely and not locally, this could be a firewall issue.

**Did flushing IP tables really do what you wanted?**  See this thread, e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61957/does-iptables-f-permanently-delete-all-iptables-rules .

**Does [this thread](http://forum.ovh.co.uk/showthread.php?8391-Open-ports) help? (OVH Open ports)**

Have you tried iptables entries for both 27015 (quoted here, from the forum thread) and 27005?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27015 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 27015 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27005 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 27005 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**Also see [this thread](http://forums.srcds.com/viewtopic/5561) about port-forwarding.**

There are a number of good port-forwarding guides on the net (top hits in Google searches have worked in the past), if that sounds like your problem.

Comment: Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-02 01:17 CEST
route_dst_netlink: can't find interface "lo"

Comment: @Ravada You don't want `lo` ; you want an an interface like eth1 ; use `ifconfig -a` to find the correct interface.   Put the output in your question (via an edit) if you are unsure.

Comment: Edited and put in the results.